# Ensures that object is unchanged?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

Is there any way using Code Contracts to ensure/check that a method does not change any members of an object, similarly to C++ `const` methods or setting all the members to `readonly`?

i.e. a simpler way than the following:

```
Contract.Ensures(this.member1 == Contract.OldValue(this.member1));
Contract.Ensures(this.member2 == Contract.OldValue(this.member2));
Contract.Ensures(this.member3 == Contract.OldValue(this.member3));
Contract.Ensures(this.member4 == Contract.OldValue(this.member4));
Contract.Ensures(this.member5 == Contract.OldValue(this.member5));
```

or the same using `Contract.EnsuresOnThrow`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Can parameters be constant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339074/c-can-parameters-be-constant)

Comment: @Sjoerd I don't think this is a duplicate, since the Op here is asking specifically if it can be done with code contracts.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I am not asking whether language/compiler can perform this check, which I know it cannot. I am asking whether the code contracts static/runtime check can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So essentially you want to check that the method is `Pure`. The [official documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/2/7/C2715F76-F56C-4D37-9231-EF8076B7EC13/userdoc.pdf) indicates that its not yet supported (see section 5.4):

```
5.4 Purity

All methods called within a contract must be pure: that is, they must not update
any pre-existing state. (A pure method is allowed to modify objects that have been
created after entry into the pure method.) Code Contract tools currently assume
the following things are pure:

* Methods marked [Pure] (If a type is marked [Pure], then that applies to all of
  its methods.) The pure attribute is dened in the contract library. (Section 4.3)

* Property getters.

* Operators (static methods whose names start with op , have one or two parameters
  and a non-void return type).

* Any method whose fully qualified name begins with
  System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract, System.String, System.IO.Path, or
  System.Type.

* Any invoked delegate, provided that the delegate type itself is attributed with
  [Pure]. The existing delegate types System.Predicate<T> and System.Comparison<T>
  are considered pure.

In the future, there will be a purity checker that will enforce these assumptions.
```

Comment: Maybe you could include the corresponding in order to complete your answer?

Comment: @ronag - Sorry, good point. I've added the documentation to the answer.

Comment: Presumably "dened" == "defined" :)

Comment: I presume - it was copied directly from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If your class implements

```
ICloneable
```

and

```
IEquatable<YourClassType>
```

as value equality (not reference equality), than you can write:

```
Contract.Ensures( 
    this.Equals ( Contract.OldValue ( (YourClassType)this.Clone() )
);
```